# How can I configure gedit to execute different languages with F5?

Tags: gedit, plugins

I have installed the [Better Python Console](http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins/BetterPythonConsole)-Plugin for gedit and I am happy with it when I view python code. But I would like to be able to execute some different languages source codes when I have opened it in gedit.

For example, I would like to run `$ g++ filename.cpp -o filename.out; ./filename.out` if I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> while I have opened a C++-file.
If I have opened a PHP-file I don't want to happen anything at all.

Is this possible?

Comment: I see that you've asked two questions but only voted once. If you accept an answer you probably find it useful, then you should also upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the *external tools* in gedit. They're found under Tools.

Create a new external tool and paste the following code into it:

```
#!/bin/sh

GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME_ROOT=`echo $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME | sed 's/\(.*\)\.tex$/\1/'`
g++ $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME_ROOT.cpp -o $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME_ROOT.out; ./$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME_ROOT.out
```

Then bind a Shortcut Key, in your case <kbd>F5</kbd>, to this tool.

And, finally press the three dots in the lower right corner (right of Applicability) and choose an option so that it only applies to C++ files.